# C++ storing custom object as blob in Mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, blob, mysql-connector

I need to store a C++ object to Mysql database as BLOB. Following is my code,

```
int MySqlDB::save(string name, TrackerFeatures features)
{
  ofstream ofs("features.ros", ios::binary);
  ofs.write((char*)&features, sizeof(features));

  try{
    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt = con->prepareStatement("insert into faces(name,features) values(?,?)");
    istream stream(ofs.rdbuf());
    pstmt->setString(1, name);
    pstmt->setBlob(2, &stream);

    pstmt->executeUpdate();
  } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
    cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
    cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
    cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I pass the data to this function, I could see the features.ros file being created with some binary data. Also, there is row created in the table but the "features" column is empty. Not sure what am I getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The raw buffer of the std::ofstream instance (named as ofs) was already empty when you are constructing the std::istream object using this raw buffer.

However, it's not a good idea to store the actual memory representation of a given object, for some reason... Instead, consider creating proper persisting methods, which gives valid and portable representation, for the desired classes.

Comment: Gabor: Could you please elaborate your point or guide me to some tutorial. Am pretty much new to C++ and is the first time doing something like this.